# Android Custom Button Font

Tags: java, android, button, fonts

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="alertBtn1"
        android:text="Hello" 
        android:textSize="22sp"
```

Above is the code for the button in the xml, and I the custom font in a folder "fonts" in the assets folder.  How can I change the font of the button to match the custom font I have?

Here is what the button does:

```
public void onClick(View v){}

public void alertBtn(View v){

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Button 1")
    .setMessage("Hello")
    .setNeutralButton("Go Back", null)
    .show();
}
```

I tried using

```
Button txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "custom_font.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

but it said `R.id.custom_font);` cannot be resolved or is not a field, and that there is a syntax error at font in `txt.setTypeface(font);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Button txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);`

Should be

`Button txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`

OR
`android:id="@+id/button1"`

should be

`android:id="@+id/custom_font"`

That will fix your cannot be resolved error, but I don't see the syntax error in the setTypeface line.

Comment: Why does it say Syntax error on token "font", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token in the line "txt.setTypeface(font);"

Comment: @CaptnBuzz : when `R.id.custom_font` is not resolved then it also give error  on `txt.setTypeface(font);` line

Comment: I think I have to declare fonts in the strings.xml because it says VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token, but how would I do that?

Comment: @CaptnBuzz : depend on where you are using current code make sure you have these lines inside onCreate of Activity after setcontentView method?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Button txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
```

to

```
Button txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and  `android:onClick="alertBtn1"` to  `android:onClick="alertBtn"` becuase you are setting `alertBtn1` in Button xml and in code part you have method with `alertBtn` name